# "Another installation is already in progress" -Java download

Tags: java

Whenever I try and install the Java JDK, I get the message "Another installation is already in progress."

I have seen all these videos that say to go into your oracle folder and then delete JAVA_INSTALL_FLAG, but I don't have that. I don't even have the oracle folder in ProgramData.
Any help?
OS: Windows 10

Comment: See https://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_1500.html

Comment: Have you tried looking in the task manager?